# mysql datetime default current timestamp

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export

Recently i was exporting one of my database from localhost to a production environment and when i tried to plonk in the .sql file, the database that i was inporting the data into returned me an error on the datetime field which is DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. From what i read online, older sql phpadmin versions do not support datetime fields as default current timestamps but rather i must use timestamps.

However, thinking that my entire platform has been structured to suit datetime, is there anything i can do without needing to find a host that supports newer sql versions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you get following error "MySQL #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: "older sql phpadmin versions" --> How about specifying the versions involved? Did you actually check that this is the case?

Comment: Yep i double checked. I couldnt add a row with datetime and default current timestamp manually as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue may be due to `'SQL_MODE'` set to `'TRADITIONAL'`.

Setting the `SQL_MODE` to either `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` would resolve the `default` values issue for `datetime` and `timestamp` type of columns.

**Refer to MySQL Documentation**:

- [Important SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important)
- [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables)
- [TRADITIONAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional)
- [ALLOW_INVALID_DATES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates)